# Float does not Align Elements beside Each Other

Tags: html, css

Live Temporary Link: http://www.tajrediat.com/test/

**Snapshot:**

[image]

*Red colored names represent classes.*

**I want my form to be by/within the white box. I could use margin-right and margin-top to get it into the box, but is there a practical way to float the form by the socialmedia section?**

**HTML:**

```
<div class="container">
        <header>
            <div class="logo">
            </div>
            <nav>
                <ul>
                    <li></li>
                    <li></li>
                    <li></li>
                    <li></li>
                </ul>
            </nav>

            <div class="mainbanner">

            </div>
            <div class="loginbox">
                <form>
                    <ul>
                        <li>
                            <label>Username</label>
                            <input type="text"/>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <label>Password</label>
                            <input type="password"/>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <input type="checkbox"/>
                            <label>Remember me?</label>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <input type="submit" value="Login"/>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </form>
            </div>
            <div class"socialmedia">
                <!-- tweeter-->
                <!-- facebook -->
                <!-- googleplus -->
            </div>
        </header> 
    </div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.container {
    width: 980px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.logo {
    float: right;   
}

nav {
    float: right;   
}

nav ul li {
    display: inline;
    padding-right: 13px;    
}

.mainbanner {
    float: right;
    margin-top: 10px;
    margin-right: 20px;
}

.socialmedia {

}

.loginbox {
    height: 182px;
    background: url(../images/loginbox.png) no-repeat;
}

.loginbox form {
width: 100px;
}

.loginbox form ul{

}
```

**If i remove the width out of .loginbox form, the form gets messy as of:**

[image]

***Any idea how float the form beside the above section, by the white box?***

Comment: Can you reproduce this in a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) or possibly provide a live link?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to give width to loginbox div and socialmedia, say something like 50%, otherwise it is going to take 100% width.
Also make sure that you clear floats

Your CSS should be something like below

```
.loginbox, .socialmedia
{
    float:left;
    width:50%;
}
.clear
{
     clear:both
}
```

Add a sibling div to loginbox and socialmedia divs and add the "clear" css class to this new div

Answer (score 0):

You need to add float: right; to .loginbox (if you want it next to the others) and give it a width that is smaller than the remaining space. Add a new div with clear: both; below that.