# Text isn't in a proper position with float: left

Tags: html, css, image, text

I've got a problem, I wanted to place a text just next to the image, as shown in the picture. But it doesn't work. I'm just starting CSS and HTML journey so don't blame please if the mistake is shameful.

I haven't forgotten about `float: left` and `clear: both` lines so I guess it may mean that the width or the height is too small to fit the text.

I'll paste a stack snippet here. The zip pack with a picture will be included as well, in case you'd like to see it how it works.

```css
body {
  background-color: #444444;
  font-family: 'Didact Gothic', sans-serif;
  font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
  font-size: 18px;
  color: white;
}

#container {
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  width: 1000px;
}

#logo {
  text-align: center;
  padding: 15px;
  background-color: #303030;
  color: white;
  font-size: 30px;
  font-weight: 900;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
}

#navbar {
  background-color: black;
  margin-top: 20px;
  padding: 10px;
}

.click {
  float: left;
  margin-left: 20px;
}

.click:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
  background-color: green;
}

#quote {
  height: 230px;
  width: 980px;
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: red;
  margin-top: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 25px;
}

#quoteL {
  float: left;
  width: 200px;
  height: 250px;
}

#quoteR {
  float: left;
  width: 800px;
  font-size: 16px;
  text-align: justify;
}

.bigtitle {
  font-size: 32px;
  font-weight: 900;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <title>Angielski - Nauka angielskiego dla zainteresowanych</title>
  <meta name="keywords" content="angielski, English, english, nauka angielskiego, angielskiego, nauka, online, nauka angielskiego online,
efektywna nauka, prosta gramatyka, gramatyka, słownictwo, tłumaczenie,
pomoc, jak" />
  <meta name="description" content="Ta strona pomoże ci nauczyć się angielskiego w wolnym czasie bez problemu i z przyjemnością!" />
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1" />

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" type="text/css" />
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Didact+Gothic|Lato:400,400i,700,900&amp;subset=latin-ext" rel="stylesheet"> </head>

<body>
  <div id="container">

    <div id="logo">English 4 Everyone :D</div>

    <div id="navbar">
      <div class="click">TO BE</div>
      <div class="click">TO HAVE/TO HAVE GOT</div>
      <div class="click">PRESENT SIMPLE</div>
      <div style="clear:both;"></div>
    </div>

    <div id="quote">
      <div id="quoteL">
        <img src="swan.jpg" />
      </div>
      <div id="quoteR">
        <span class="bigtitle">Quote to success:</span> "Our job in grammar teaching is not to describe the language, as a grammarian does.It is to build a bridge from A (what the student knows) to B (what we want him/her to know next). If the bridge
        is too long it will collapse." ~Michael Swan source: https://mikeswan.net/some-things-i-believe/
      </div>
      <div style="clear: both;"></div>
    </div>

  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Pictures:

[image]

HTML, CSS and jpg file inside a zip file on [Google Drive](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Rl1O3wP2_6D1PfU8M6eBqosMzNqEEpYK/view?usp=sharing).

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8520392/float-does-not-align-elements-beside-each-other

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the `width` of `#quoteL`+`#quoteR`<=`#quote` 
and if you want that `img` **do not out** of red section change the `height` to be **smaller** then `#quote` `height`

```css
    body {
    background-color: #444444;
    font-family: 'Didact Gothic', sans-serif;
    font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
    font-size: 18px;
    color: white; }

    #container {
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    width: 1000px; }

    #logo {
    text-align: center;
    padding: 15px;
    background-color: #303030;
    color: white;
    font-size: 30px;
    font-weight: 900;
    margin-bottom: 30px; }

    #navbar {
    background-color: black;
    margin-top: 20px;
    padding: 10px; }

    .click {
    float: left;
    margin-left: 20px; } .click:hover {
    cursor: pointer;
    background-color: green; }

    #quote {
    height: 230px;
    width: 980px;
    padding: 10px;
    background-color: red;
    margin-top: 20px;
    margin-bottom: 25px; }

    #quoteL {
    float: left;  width: 180px;
    height: 180px; }

    #quoteR {
    float: left;
    width: 800px;  font-size: 16px;  text-align: justify; }
#quoteL img{ height: 210px;}
    .bigtitle {
    font-size: 32px;  font-weight: 900;  letter-spacing: 2px;
display: block;

 }
```

```html
    <!DOCTYPE HTML> <html> <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Angielski - Nauka angielskiego dla zainteresowanych</title>   
    <meta name="keywords" content="angielski, English, english, nauka angielskiego, angielskiego, nauka, online, nauka angielskiego online,
    efektywna nauka, prosta gramatyka, gramatyka, słownictwo, tłumaczenie,
    pomoc, jak" />
    <meta name="description" content="Ta strona pomoże ci nauczyć się angielskiego w wolnym czasie bez problemu i z przyjemnością!" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1" />
    
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" type="text/css" />
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Didact+Gothic|Lato:400,400i,700,900&amp;subset=latin-ext"
    rel="stylesheet"> </head> <body>
        <div id="container">
           
            <div id="logo">English 4 Everyone :D</div>
            
            <div id="navbar">
                <div class="click">TO BE</div>
                <div class="click">TO HAVE/TO HAVE GOT</div>
                <div class="click">PRESENT SIMPLE</div>
                <div style="clear:both;"></div>
            </div>
            
            <div id="quote">
               <div id="quoteL">
                    <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/8hZeG.jpg" />
                </div>
                <div id="quoteR">
                    <span  class="bigtitle">Quote to success:</span>
                    "Our job in grammar teaching is not to describe the language, as a grammarian does.It is to build a bridge from A
    (what the student knows) to B (what we want him/her to know next). If
    the bridge is too long it will collapse." ~Michael Swan
                    source: https://mikeswan.net/some-things-i-believe/
                </div>
                <div style="clear: both;"></div>
            </div>
            
            </div> </body> </html>
```

Comment: tell me if you need more help

Comment: Text needs some replacing, I guess using margins it will work, but still I've got a space between an image, I want to cover. The image is too low as well. Though it's in the "red div object block". Thank you for helping!

Comment: use margin only for rigth and top/bottom without left to prevent space

Comment: do you want the image in center of red section height?

Comment: No, I'd rather achieve a text glued to the top of the red block (the title which is in bold) and then some <br />'s to separate the other text.
I'd like to add some margin-top so that it's not that "glued" to the top of this <div>.

At now I'm using the other method, it works, but at now the width is a bit higher than the rest of objects in this page.
https://imgur.com/a/0wTHX6I
It's the code which was written by Paul Tanne, in the comments in his section I wrote few changes which I applied so that the image fits right, but there's still too much of width here.

Comment: I saw your edit, now it works as I wanted. Thank you for your help. I'm new in this site, is there an option that I could reward you for the best answer?

Comment: And how can I close the answered question, if I'm able to?

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/111630/how-to-mark-a-question-on-so-as-resolved

Comment: And now if I marked an answer, the question is closed or still open? Do I have to do some further actions?

Comment: yes people can see it and add answer but if answer mark it means that people look at this as best answer

Answer (score 0):

the sum of quoteL and quoteR is not equal to quote, you can change him or if you want you can do % instead of px for see better the size :)

```
#quote
{
    height: 230px;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 10px;
    background-color: red;
    margin-top: 20px;
    margin-bottom: 25px;
}

#quoteL
{
    float: left;
    width: 20%;
    height: 250px;
}

#quoteR
{
    float: left;
    margin-left: 5%;
    width: 70%;
    font-size: 16px;
    text-align: justify;
}
#logo
{
    text-align: center;
    padding: 10px;
    background-color: #303030;
    color: white;
    font-size: 30px;
    font-weight: 900;
    margin-bottom: 30px;
    width:100%;
}

#navbar
{
    background-color: black;
    margin-top: 20px;
    padding: 10px;
    width:100%;
}
```

Comment: It's almost what I wanted, I changed a bit the code, that the whole picture is in the right block. Though, the width isn't satisfying, I wanted to crop this side a bit... Should I changed the value of % somewhere to reach my willingness?

`    #quote
{
height: 260px;
width: 100%;
padding: 10px;
background-color: red;
margin-top: 20px;
margin-bottom: 25px;
}`

I actually add a bit of height to make the picture fit in there.
Picture which shows my current problem:
https://imgur.com/a/0wTHX6I

Comment: look the edit :) sometimes u put a padding of 15 px and sometimes 10 px. i put a width 100% in all your bloc and put the padding to 10 px :)

Comment: I'd like to meet you IRL paul tanné, such a css pro !

Answer (score 0):

Add this to ur quoteR

```
#quoteR {
  float: left;
  width: calc(100% - 200px); /*200px is width of image*/
  font-size: 16px;
  text-align: justify;
  padding-left: 10px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

Using **calc**, u can subtract the width of the image from the parent's width. the value of **calc** will be assigned to the **#quoteR**

```css
body {
  background-color: #444444;
  font-family: 'Didact Gothic', sans-serif;
  font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
  font-size: 18px;
  color: white;
}

#container {
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  width: 1000px;
}

#logo {
  text-align: center;
  padding: 15px;
  background-color: #303030;
  color: white;
  font-size: 30px;
  font-weight: 900;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
}

#navbar {
  background-color: black;
  margin-top: 20px;
  padding: 10px;
}

.click {
  float: left;
  margin-left: 20px;
}

.click:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
  background-color: green;
}

#quote {
  /*height: 230px;*/
  width: 980px;
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: red;
  margin-top: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 25px;
  clear: both;
}

#quoteL {
  float: left;
  width: 200px;
  height: 250px;
}

#quoteR {
  float: left;
  width: calc(100% - 200px);
  font-size: 16px;
  text-align: justify;
  padding-left: 10px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.bigtitle {
  font-size: 32px;
  font-weight: 900;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <title>Angielski - Nauka angielskiego dla zainteresowanych</title>
  <meta name="keywords" content="angielski, English, english, nauka angielskiego, angielskiego, nauka, online, nauka angielskiego online,
    efektywna nauka, prosta gramatyka, gramatyka, słownictwo, tłumaczenie,
    pomoc, jak" />
  <meta name="description" content="Ta strona pomoże ci nauczyć się angielskiego w wolnym czasie bez problemu i z przyjemnością!" />
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1" />

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" type="text/css" />
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Didact+Gothic|Lato:400,400i,700,900&amp;subset=latin-ext" rel="stylesheet"> </head>

<body>
  <div id="container">

    <div id="logo">English 4 Everyone :D</div>

    <div id="navbar">
      <div class="click">TO BE</div>
      <div class="click">TO HAVE/TO HAVE GOT</div>
      <div class="click">PRESENT SIMPLE</div>
      <div style="clear:both;"></div>
    </div>

    <div id="quote">
      <div id="quoteL">
        <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/8hZeG.jpg]" />
      </div>
      <div id="quoteR">
        <span class="bigtitle">Quote to success:</span> "Our job in grammar teaching is not to describe the language, as a grammarian does.It is to build a bridge from A (what the student knows) to B (what we want him/her to know next). If the bridge
        is too long it will collapse." ~Michael Swan source: https://mikeswan.net/some-things-i-believe/
      </div>
      <div style="clear: both;"></div>
    </div>

  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: It works, thanks, but one more thing - is there a possibility to cut a bit of width here shown in this picture (the part which the blue line cuts):
https://imgur.com/a/fkqjBz5

If there isn't I will resize other <div> block so that they will look similarly. Thank you for the time spent for helping me!

Comment: @znaczki654 its similar to ur image,the red div is iside

Answer (score 0):

You can use a table to take that whole description to the right of the image. Refer the following html code.

```
<div id="logo">English 4 Everyone :D</div>

<div id="navbar">
  <div class="click">TO BE</div>
  <div class="click">TO HAVE/TO HAVE GOT</div>
  <div class="click">PRESENT SIMPLE</div>
  <div style="clear:both;"></div>
</div>

<table id="quote">
<tr>
  <td>
    <div id="quoteL">
      <img src="swan.jpg" />
    </div>
  </td>
  <td>
    <div id="quoteR">
    <span class="bigtitle">Quote to success:</span> "Our job in grammar teaching is not to describe the language, as a grammarian does.It is to build a bridge from A (what the student knows) to B (what we want him/her to know next). If the bridge
    is too long it will collapse." ~Michael Swan source: https://mikeswan.net/some-things-i-believe/
  </div>
  </td>
</tr>     

  <div style="clear: both;"></div>
</table>
```